# How to make DB query MINUS working with Laravel query builder

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I have one table. In the table there are two sets of data:

1. Set A
2. Set B

I want to get (A - B), i.e. items/rows which are part of A and not of B.

For illustration I have created following table with two columns:

| id | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 |
| 2 | a | 2 |
| 3 | a | 5 |
| 4 | b | 2 |
| 5 | b | 6 |
| 6 | b | 1 |

Set A = { row: row.X == a }  ( all the rows having X column value equal to **a**)

Set B = { row: row.X == b }  ( all the rows having X column value equal to **b**)

I would like to get list rows in A where A.Y is **not equal** (!=) to B.Y. If you look at above table only 3rd row meet the criteria.

| id | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | a | 5 |

In SQL the MINUS operator do the trick. But there is no corresponding method in Laravel's query builder.

What will be best way this can be achieved using join/left-join method? Any other alternatives?

Comment: You can easily do by db::raw method to achieve such query

Comment: Can you provide me a raw query?

Comment: Get all the values where(X,a) as A... Then Get values where(X,b) as B ... then I'm db::raw(A-B)